# Wordpress - Query comments by post meta

Tags: wordpress, comments, post-meta

I am using the code below (simplified) to display a list of the last 10 comments:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'tarefa',
    'number'         => '10',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'comment_date',
    //'meta_key'        => 'field_name',
    //'meta_value'      => 'field_value',
);

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '<br>'; //post title
    echo $comment->comment_content; // comment content
    echo '</p>';
};

?>
```

**Question:**

Well, *meta_key* and *meta_value* seem to be associated to **comment_meta**... But in my case, I have to display comments based on **post_meta** key and value.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.
You need to add a query for posts to get array of post ides with meta key.
Then use that array into comments query argument.

```
//QUERY FOR POSTS WITH META KEY AND VALUE (META QUERY)
$post_args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_key'     => 'meta key',//Meta key of post
    'meta_value'   => 'meta value',//String or Numeric value
    'meta_compare' => '=',
);
$post_query = new WP_Query( $post_args );
$posts_array= array();
if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();

        $posts_array[] = get_the_ID(); //Array of post ids

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}



//YOUR COMMENT ARGS SHOULD BE THIS
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'tarefa',
    'number'         => '10',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'comment_date',
    'post__in'        => $posts_array, //THIS IS THE ARRAY OF POST IDS WITH META QUERY
);
```

Try this , then let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

My first question here at Stackoverflow and that worked perfectly.

Thank you very much, Souvik!

Below the final result (simplified):

```
$post_args = array(
  'post_type'              => 'tarefa',
  'posts_per_page'         => -1,
  'meta_key'               => 'field_name',
  'meta_value'             => 'field_value',
);
$post_query = new WP_Query( $post_args );
$posts_array= array();
if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $posts_array[] = get_the_ID(); //Array of post ids
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

//YOUR COMMENT ARGS SHOULD BE THIS
$args = array(
    'number'         => '30',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'comment_date',
    'post__in'        => $posts_array, //THIS IS THE ARRAY OF POST IDS WITH META QUERY
);

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID) . '<br>'; //post title
    echo $comment->comment_content; // comment content
    echo '</p>';
};
```